# Having problems in animated stop-show-hide in a menu

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

The problem is that I can't figure out why the animated sub-menus displaying are not working.
When I comment out the '.stop()' and '.animate()' and uncomment the '.css()' line, I roughly get what I need. I don't understand why the animate together with stop are not working.

My js portion :

```
    function sub_menu_disp(a){
        a.children('div')
        .stop()
        .animate({'display':'block'},'slow');
        //.css({'display':'block'});
    };

    function sub_menu_hide(a){
        a.children('div')
        .stop()
        .animate({'display':'none'},'slow');
        //.css({'display':'none'});
    };

    $(document).ready(function(e){
        $('#one,#two')
            .children('div')
            .hide()
            .css({'overflow':'hidden'});

        $('#one,#two').bind('mouseover',function(){
            sub_menu_disp($(this));
        });

        $('#one,#two').bind('mouseout',function(){
            sub_menu_hide($(this));
        });
    });
```

My html portion:

```
    <div id='one'>
        <p>level 1</p>
        <div>
            <div>sublevel 1a</div>
            <div>sublevel 1b</div>
            <div>sublevel 1d</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div id='two'>          
        <h5>level 2</h5>
        <div>
            <div><a href='javascript:alert("hello world");'>js alert</a></div>
            <div><a href='http://facebook.com'>facebook             </a></div>
            <div><a href='http://twitter.com'>twitter               </a></div>
            <div><a href='http://google.com'>google                 </a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have kept my complete example here : http://jsfiddle.net/x382x/1/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered using an existing accordion menu plugin? There are dozens of them out there.

Comment: @mu does he really need a whole plugin?

Comment: @roXon: It is tricky to get the behavior just right if it is to be hover based and neither of the two (current) answers work with hovers. Why reinvent the wheel when there are already several working ones to choose from?

Comment: @mu -- i do not really need a full plugin. I'd prefer a small codes.

Comment: @mu - you know what I think about 'reinventing the wheel'. if not: "*Sometimes reinventing the wheel... makes the wheel a bit rounder*" :D ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking from an end-user perspective - Hover is a bad idea: Your intent to impress the visitor may become *'a "shaky" experience!'*

**USE CLICK!**
May I suggest you something like this?

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/2b5FW/)

```
$('.cont').hide();
$('.el>*').click(function() {
    var d = $(this).next('.cont');
    check = (d.is(':visible')) ? d.slideUp() : ($('.cont').slideUp()) (d.slideDown());
});
```

---

If you still want to use the 'hover' ability...
just change line 2:

```
$('.el>*').mouseenter(function() {
```

Comment: @roXon-- Yes, I understand the point. I have already added an option to choose between click and hover. I personally choose click but I was told to prefer hover ...

Comment: glad it worked. you can also use mouseenter as edited above. @maan81

Comment: @maan81 You should always accept answers that solve your problem. Please see the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Comment: Sorry for the delay. 

I am having a slight problem on hover. The sub-menus hide when I move off from the main menu to sub-menu. I was looking if I could make it better by not hiding the sub-menus as long as the pointer is over the sub-menus too.

Answer (score 2):

I think `animate` works only on numeric css properties. You could use `show('slow')` and `hide('slow')`.

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jV3RM/)

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#one,#two').children('div').hide().css({
        'overflow': 'hidden'
    });
    $('#one,#two').hover(function() {
        $(this).children('div').stop(true, true).show('slow');
    }, function() {
        $(this).children('div').stop(true, true).hide('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: You might want to use `.hover` instead of `mouseover/mouseout`, this starts acting up as soon as you mouseover the inner `<div>`.

Comment: Better but if you move your mouse up and down faster than `'slow'` you'll see jumpiness. I'm not trying to give you a hard time, it is just that hover-based accordions are very tricky to get right.

Comment: @mu Yes I understand. I guess it's best to avoid a hover based UI or use a battle tested plugin instead of rolling something of your own.

Comment: +1 for a good answer and a help with your 'acceptance' comment. thx